# Draw an arrow and then rotate it about its start point AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two classes:Arrow and RotateToMouse. Arrow takes in two points and draws an arrow between the two. RotateToMouse should rotate the arrow about its start point to always point to the mouse, but it seems to rotate about the origin instead. How do I cause it to move its rotation point? Arrow takes in a1, a2 (points) and col (a color).

Here is RotateToMouse:

```
package{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.geom.Point;
public class RotateToMouse extends Sprite{
private var arr:Arrow;
}
public function RotateToMouse(arr:Arrow){
this.arr=arr;
init();
}

private function init():void{
addChild(arr);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame;
}

public function onEnterFrame(evt:Event):void{
    var diffx:Number=mouseX-arr.a2.x;
    var diffy:Number=mouseX-arr.a2.y;
    var radians:Number=Math.atan2(diffy, diffx);
    arr.rotation=radians*180/Math.PI;
}
```

and I have another file, arrowdrawing.fla, that has on frame 1 actionscript that says:

```
    var arr:Arrow=new Arrow(new Point(40, 50), new Point(450, 400), 0x000000);
    var rotarr:RotateToMouse(arr);
    addChild(rotarr);
```

As asked, here is the Arrow class:
    package{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.geom.Point;

```
public class Arrow extends Sprite{
public var a1:Point;
public var a2:Point;
private var col:uint;
private var dx:Number;
private var dy:Number;
private var angle:Number;
private var thdiff:Number=30; //angle of arrowhead is 30
private var len:Number=20; //length of arrowhead is 20
private var bangle:Number;
private var cangle:Number;

public function Arrow(a1:Point, a2:Point, col:uint){
    //constructor code
    this.col=col;
    this.a1=a1;
    this.a2=a2;
    dx=a2.x-a1.x;
    dy=a2.y-a1.y;   
}

public function init():void{
//draws a line between a1 and a2 of color col
    graphics.lineStyle(3, col);
    graphics.beginFill(col);
    graphics.moveTo(a1.x, a1.y);
    graphics.lineTo(a2.x, a2.y);
    graphics.endFill();
    drawArrowHead();
}

public function getCos(n:Number){
    //n will be given in degrees; we need to convert it to radians
    return Math.cos(n*Math.PI/180);
}
public function getSin(n:Number){
    //n will be given in degrees; we need to convert it to radians
    return Math.sin(n*Math.PI/180);
}
//arrow head consists of 2 points, b=(b1, b2) and c=(c1, c2)
public function drawArrowHead():void{
    //find the angle of the line we start with
    angle=Math.atan2(dx, dy);
    //for c,b we are going to figure out what the angle is of the lines to either side
    bangle=angle*(180/Math.PI)-thdiff;
    cangle=angle*(180/Math.PI)+thdiff;
    //point b, c are flipped around so that they can start from a2 (the endpoint)
    var b1:Number=a2.x-(len*getCos(bangle));
    var b2:Number=a2.y-(len*getSin(bangle));
    var c1:Number=a2.x-(len*getCos(cangle));
    var c2:Number=a2.y-(len*getSin(cangle));
//draw arrohead from a2 to b, and c
    graphics.lineStyle(3, col);
    graphics.beginFill(col);
    graphics.moveTo(a2.x, a2.y);
    graphics.lineTo(b1, b2);
    graphics.lineTo(c1, c2);
    graphics.lineTo(a2.x, a2.y);
    graphics.endFill();
    drawArrowHead();

}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On the `Arrow` class you must draw it in such a way that the rotation point lies at (0, 0). I don't know how you are doing at the moment (it would be useful to see the `Arrow` class declaration), but you have to keep in mind that each object has a different origin position.

The most probable error is that you are creating the arrow object at stage position (0, 0) (or simply creating and not moving).

```
 --------------
|*             |
|              |
|   ------>    |
|              |
|              |
|              |
 --------------
```

Where `*` is the arrow position (x, y) == (0, 0). In this case what you have to do is move the arrow to the start position, and when drawing subtract that value from all points:

```
 --------------
|              |
|              |
|   *----->    |
|              |
|              |
|              |
 --------------
```

It will look exactly the same, but the rotation behavior will be different.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know of to rotate around a pivot point is to record the pivot point's location according to the target's parent, do the rotation, and because you know that the local pivot point shouldn't have changed in relation to the parent, adjust the x,y by the difference.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.geom.Matrix;

/**
 * Sets the rotation of the given sprite to [newRotation], rotating around [pivotPoint].
 * @param target The sprite to set the rotation.
 * @param pivotPoint The local point to rotate around. This is in the coordinate space of the target.
 * @param newRotation (Degrees) the rotation in degrees to apply to target.
 */
function pivotRotate(target:Sprite, pivotPoint:Point, newRotation:Number) {
    var pivotPointParent:Point = target.transform.matrix.transformPoint(pivotPoint);
    target.rotation = newRotation;
    var pivotPointParent2:Point = target.transform.matrix.transformPoint(pivotPoint);
    var diff:Point = pivotPointParent2.subtract(pivotPointParent);
    target.x -= diff.x;
    target.y -= diff.y;
}

pivotRotate(arrow, new Point(15, 30), 90);
```

Comment: This almost works. I'm still trying to get it to point to my mouse, but (for example) if the arrow initially points down, to the left and the mouse goes up to the right it will start spinning continuously. Does this have to do with the way I change x and y?